# Errors while restarting Tomcat server 7?

Tags: java, tomcat

**First error:**

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

*Caused by:*

```
java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

**Second error**

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component  [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
```

*Caused by:*

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
```

I am doing nothing just restarting Tomcat server 7 in Netbeans and also I'm using the matched version of Java SE which is 7.
Also I have cross- checked the `server.xml` to find out that the value of port and redirectPort should not be same.

```
<Server port="5005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="5000" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Comment: Similar to [Tomcat not starting (throwing java.net.BindException: )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481092/tomcat-not-starting-throwing-java-net-bindexception) or [Tomcat cannot start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576435/tomcat-cannot-start)?

Comment: @downshift thanks it really helped..actually the problem is in port:8009 is already used by some other process i have to kill it and the error gone... feel free to post it as a answer I will accept it. once again thanks :)

Comment: Great! I'm glad those references helped. I'm not sure if I can take credit for only reference other answers, but since those other answers directed you shut down the other process running on port 8009, I'll gladly accept your offer =D thanks you too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, OP palak sharma stated the problem was another process was already running on port:8009. After killing that process running on port 8009, the error was gone and the tomcat server started up without error as expected.